# Groovy override static getAt (subscript) operator

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I am trying to override the static `getAt` operator in Groovy. It runs OK but I am stumped by a nasty warning in IntelliJ.

```
class SubscriptTest {

    static def map = [
        (SubscriptKey.ONE)  : 'one',
        (SubscriptKey.TWO)  : 'two',
        (SubscriptKey.THREE): 'three',
    ]

    static Object getAt(SubscriptKey key) {
        map[key]
    }
}

enum SubscriptKey {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
}
```

When I run

```
println SubscriptTest[SubscriptKey.ONE]
```

It prints `one`. But I also get the below warning in IntelliJ.

> 'getAt' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to '(SubscriptKey)'

Not sure how to fix / suppress this warning.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to override the static getAt operator in Groovy

There is no static `getAt` method, there's a [not-static `getAt` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#getAt(java.lang.String)). Here's an example of how to override the non-static `getAt` method

```
// run this code in the Groovy console
class SubscriptTest {

    static def map = [
        (SubscriptKey.ONE)  : 'one',
        (SubscriptKey.TWO)  : 'two',
        (SubscriptKey.THREE): 'three',
    ]

    Object getAt(String key) {
        'overriden getAt invoked'
    }
}

enum SubscriptKey {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
}

assert new SubscriptTest()['key'] == 'overriden getAt invoked'
```

Comment: I also think it's a way IntelliJ parses your code, and tries to match `getAt` with [DefaultGroovyMethods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) As a workaround you could try to find and disable inspection rule in an editor.